# ADAL, Angular 6 - returning url parameters

Tags: angular, angular6, adal.js

I have used the ADAL for angular 6 library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

When returning from AzureAD following are added to the URL. This is not very user friendly, is it possible to avoid having these parameters?

https://localhost:44355/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdfWnVmMXR2a3dMeFlhSFMzcTZsVWpVWUlHdyIsImtpZCI6IjdfWnVmMXR2a3dMeFlhSFMzcTZsVWpVWUlHdyJ9.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.r128N1nhhSFIOlKnluBMh5FdFS2PEKdxG8KndMLDon19CkZh3FlYvKH6J274m17Edn1-l1wMLd5sj0D94WbgVF1GfABUTwg_dXWJso7Rl6kD6xVb-p3f5wrh8APWPVdCNYezKZ3I95jOCtFEaCaA4YdBi7c_xxx-aMBXkG9NWL0fjdikHYS1g82hwPpekxmW0zQTryxlGOfHf5g0Y-tk_Q-gOasJuqJ4voM-xUBPqRgC1TNE2sApdbl1UnKoTdEsjWOJ0SnEpjg1sK6B2JD1aOLS509TtGlszvkObBLXsYmf0eako7iw2sWEXidxQYH1ELElMnX895Og&state=5f601453-c535-40ba-adff-f7778db01a55&session_state=xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` to `true` In your `app.module.ts` where you've imported the library config:

```
imports: [
...
    MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
      tenant: 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
      clientId: 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx',
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      endpoints: {
        'https://example.com/api/': 'api'
      },
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, <----- Make sure this is set to 'true'
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
    })
...
```

When set to `true`, the token will still show up in the URL, but only for a short moment. I don't think it's possible to change this, as it seems to be a configuration from the library itself.

Comment: I found out there is a function called handleWindow. Calling this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by setting the URL template on the operation screen in the publisher portal. Just include the parameters you wish to forward on to your backend, the others will not be.

Alternatively, you can use the [set-query-parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894083.aspx#SetQueryStringParameter) policy, which gives you full control of the parameters you are using.

Azure AD application requires that a concrete and absolute url is registered as the return/reply url, so it is not possible to dynamically change url paths and parameters.

Comment: Publisher portal? Do you mean the AzureAD app registration?